# TypeScript: How to add a property to a class with a string as the identifier

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

I have a list of string values, they represent the identifiers of the fields that I want to add to a class.

**For example:**

I have a string array:

```
let stringArr = ['player1score', 'player2score', 'player3score'];
```

After some conversion code, I want the result to be like:

```
{player1score: 100, player2score: 100, player3score: 100}
```

What should I do?

```
let row = {};
stringArr.forEach(player => {
    // What should I do here?
    // something like row.addProp(player, score)?
});
```

**Note:**

I have to do this conversion because I need to display a graph of the data using v-charts, and the final rows data would have to look like this:

```
let rows = [
    {time: ..., player1score: ..., player2score: ..., player3score: ...},
    ...
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a new key in the object with the value you want

```
let row = {};
stringArr.forEach(player => {
    row[player] = 100;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create the object using JavaScript's bracket notation:

```
let stringArr = ['player1score', 'player2score', 'player3score'];
let row = {};
stringArr.forEach(player => row[player] = 100);
// row = {player1score: 100, player2score: 100, player3score: 100}
```

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

In modern browser you can do [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries)

```js
let stringArr = ['player1score', 'player2score', 'player3score'];

let obj = Object.fromEntries(stringArr.map(val => [val, 100]))

console.log(obj)
```